# Wordpress Page Paginate

Tags: pagination, wordpress

I'm using the Leaf theme in Wordpress and the page only posts a maximum of 10 posts.  I want there to be a bottom bar paginating to older (or newer) posts but am not sure how to accomplish this.  There is a leaf_pagination function however it does not work on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) or [WP-Paginate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/) plugin.  For WP-PageNavi plugin you just need to replace below code

```
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
```

in template file with

```
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

Comment: this would work however there is a leaf_pagination function already that does not work. i believe its an issue with the loop file

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-issue-10?replies=3 to find a solution in the home.php file.